# Deformable terrain in OpenGL 2D [Worms like]

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

I've searched for a while and I've heard of different ways to do this, so I thought I'd come here and see what I should do,

From what I've gathered I should use.. glBitmap and 0s and 0xFF values in the array to make the terrain. Any input on this?
I tried switching it to quads, but I'm not sure that is efficient and the way its meant to be done.

I want the terrain to be able to have tunnels, such as worms. 2 Dimensional.

Here is what I've tried so far,

I've tried to make a glBitmap, so..

```
pixels = pow(2 * radius, 2);
ras = new GLubyte[pixels];
```

and then set them all to 0xFF, and drew it using glBitmap(x, y, 0, 0, ras);
This could be then checked for explosions and what not and whatever pixels could be set to zero. Is this a plausible approach? I'm not too good with opengl, can I put a texture on a glBitmap? From what I've seen it I don't think you can.

Comment: OpenGL is just for drawing; deforming the terrain is something your code would do, by manipulating data in memory, *between* drawing frames via OpenGL.  Is a heightfield terrain OK, or do you need it to support things like caves and overhangs?  (Heightfields are much simpler.)

Comment: Yea, I'd enjoy terrain like worms, with the ability to makes tunnels.

Comment: You should really double-check your question before posting and provide more relevant details and/or examples.

Comment: Sorry, I posted this late last night. I have edited it too be more clear with a little [bad] example of my attempt :!

Comment: I think your question should be migrated to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the stencil buffer. You mark destroyed parts of the terrain in the stencil buffer and then draw your terrain with stencil testing enabled with a simple quad without manually testing each pixel.

Comment: I'm looking into this, seems like a good idea.. Just have to look up stencil buffer, never played with it.

Comment: @Fouf - Have a look on gamedev.stackexchange.com for more info, e.g. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13765/stencil-buffer-mask-calculation and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-stencil-buffer-more-precisely-what-is-a-stencil-in

Comment: Hmm, I've played around and got the stencil buffer working, I was just curious.. how can I retrieve this data.. as I want to make this game multiplayer, how can I tell clients.. where the area has been destroyed?

Comment: You can read the stencil buffer with `glReadPixels` but if I was to implement such a thing I would keep references of deformations in terms of shapes and synchronise it between clients(and draw them to the stencil buffer). GL drivers don't work fast when communicating from the graphics hardware to the application side, plus it might be slow to synchronize the whole stencil buffer.

Comment: One more thing, in case your map will render to an area that is bigger than the screen, or you might zoom in an out, you will anyway need to redraw the stencil buffer. Therefore depending on the current stencil buffer won't be very useful.

Comment: Alright thanks, that does seem like a better idea. Thanks for all your help. So for anything that effects terrain, I would record what happened to it. Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 3):

OK, this is a high-level overview, and I'm assuming you're familiar with OpenGL basics like buffer objects already.  Let me know if something doesn't make sense or if you'd like more details.

---

The most common way to represent terrain in computer graphics is a heightfield:  a grid of points that are spaced regularly on the X and Y axes, but whose Z (height) can vary.  A heightfield can only have one Z value per (X,Y) grid point, so you can't have "overhangs" in the terrain, but it's usually sufficient anyway.

A simple way to draw a heightfield terrain is with a triangle strip (or quads, but they're deprecated).  For simplicity, start in one corner and issue vertices in a zig-zag order down the column, then go back to the top and do the next column, and so on.  There are optimizations that can be done for better performance, and more sophisticated ways of constructing the geometry for better appearance, but that'll get you started.

(I'm assuming a rectangular terrain here since that's how it's commonly done; if you really want a circle, you can substitute  and  for X and Y so you have a polar grid.)

The coordinates for each vertex will need to be stored in a buffer object, as usual.  When you call `glBufferData()` to load the vertex data into the GPU, specify a *usage* parameter of either `GL_STREAM_DRAW` if the terrain will usually change from one frame to the next, or `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` if it will change often but not (close to) every frame.  To change the terrain, call `glBufferData()` again to copy a different set of vertex data to the GPU.

For the vertex data itself, you can specify all three coordinates (X, Y, and Z) for each vertex; that's the simplest thing to do.  Or, if you're using a recent enough GL version and you want to be sophisticated, you should be able to calculate the X and Y coordinates in the vertex shader using `gl_VertexID` and the dimensions of the grid (passed to the shader as a uniform value).  That way, you only have to store the Z values in the buffer, which means less GPU memory and bandwidth consumed.

Comment: Actually I want to be able to do tunneling, just like worms. Sorry for not being clear, +1.

Comment: And also yes, I'm going with the simpler 2D, I believe what you have posted is 3D, but I'm not 100% sure. : o

Comment: After the question update this answer, though generally a good one, doesn't answer the question in anymore. Well, it didn't even before.